# Element Match $elematch Returns all nested field

Tags: mongodb

I was working on a collection that has following format:

```
{_id:"star",
menu:[
{
  "cat_id":"123",
  "cat_name":"Cars",
  "items":[
     {
       "item_id":"i10",
     },
     {
       "item_id":"i20"
     }
  ]
},
{
  "cat_id":"345",
  "cat_name":"Trucks",
  "items":[
     {
     },
     {
     }
  ]
},
{
  "cat_id":"456",
  "cat_name":"Buses",
  "items":[
     {
     },
     {
     }
  ]
}

]
}
```

I am trying to fetch the item with item_id:"i10".
I executed following query:

```
db.item_store.find({},
{ "_id" : "star", 
  "menu" : { "$elemMatch" : { "items" : { "$elemMatch" : { 
 "item_id" : "i10" } } } } })
```

This query returns entire array of cat_id 123. Output:

```
{_id:"star",
    menu:[
    {
      "cat_id":"123",
      "cat_name":"Cars",
      "items":[
         {
           "item_id":"i10",
         },
         {
           "item_id":"i20"
         }
      ]
    }]
}
```

It should only return item with id "i10".

Even this returned same output:

```
db.merchant_menu.find({ "_id" : "star", "menu" : { "$elemMatch" : { "items" : { "$elemMatch" : { "item_id" : "i10" } } } } },{'menu.items.$':1})
```

Also, How should I modify the above query to include `cat_id`  in query condition? `cat_id` is known to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use aggregation for this by first doing an **[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** operation on the menu array early in the aggregation then do a match on the items array with `item_id`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$menu"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "menu.items.item_id":"i20"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$menu.items"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "menu.items.item_id":"i20"
        }
    }
])
```

which results in:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "star",
            "menu" : {
                "cat_id" : "123",
                "cat_name" : "Cars",
                "items" : {
                    "item_id" : "i20"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```